# Visual C++ GetModuleFileName() Problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++, window

I have used the following code to open the executable file when a button is pressed:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"Open", buffer, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

I am now trying to open a PDF file by replacing the NULL with the PDF file name as shown:

```
GetModuleFileName(_T("testt.pdf"),buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [10]' to 'HMODULE'
```

Once this works, the exe file will be kept in a folder with the PDF but the directory for this file may be changed, will this code update automatically to accommodate for this since I have used the GetModuleFileName? Also, could someone please explain to me how I would fix this code?

Thank you.

Comment: To invoke shell commands (Windows Explorer), you should use Shell functions like ShellExecute. `GetModuleFileName` is entirety different thing

Comment: Use System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("testt.pdf") instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think calling:

```
 GetModuleFileName(_T("testt.pdf"),buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

will open a PDF file?

this function is defined as follows:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileName(
  _In_opt_  HMODULE hModule,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpFilename,
  _In_      DWORD nSize
);
```

---

example to comment:

```
ShellExecuteW(
    NULL, L"open",
    L"C:\\my.pdf",
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please tell me what I would modify to open the PDF?

Comment: I think you should use: ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"Open", buffer, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); but in buffer put path to your pdf.

Comment: I have changed it to TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = L"testt.pdf"; and the app still opens itself as it did in the above code, I also tried the same with the directory and the same happened again. Could you please explain to me how I would do this? I apologize for not understanding what you probably consider simple but I am new to this and really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe your app is registered as default to open pdf files?

Comment: I also tried: TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = gcnew String("testt.pdf"); and when I pressed the button a pop up message came up saying An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. 

It had options to continue or break and I tried both, nothing happened. Also, I can open PDF's directly using shellexecute and specifiying the directory, the problems occur when I use getmodulefilename.

Comment: GetModuleFileName is used to find file pathname to module loaded in current process, for example you can find path to exe for your application.

Comment: If I want to find the file name for the PDF which is in the same file as the executable will this work?

Comment: I am not sure how pdf file is in the exe file (appended to its end?), but if that is the case then yes GetModuleFileName will find it.